# Will Ubuntu 12.04 64bit run on a Intel Celeron 900?

Tags: 64-bit, intel

I have a Intel Celeron 900 @ 2.20 ghz will it run or does it require a amd 64bit proccesor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intel [Celeron 900](http://ark.intel.com/products/41498/Intel-Celeron-Processor-900-%281M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29) is actually a single-core version of the [*Core 2 Duo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_microprocessors#Celeron_.28single-core.29_4) processors. **It supports 64-bit** and Ubuntu 12.04 x64 will run just fine on it.

However, if you have less than 1GB of RAM you should consider running the 32-bit version for performance reasons.

*The 64-bit version of Ubuntu will run on **any PC (or Mac) with a 64-bit Intel or AMD processor**. The `amd` in `amd64` doesn't mean that this architecture is AMD-specific. The first 64-bit processors for PC's were made by AMD; it's for that historical reason that the architecture name has `amd` in it.*